# How to convert this MATLAB script to SCILAB?

Tags: matlab, scilab

```
% P0211a: To prove that the system T1[x(n)] = x(n)u(n) is linear
clear; clc; close all;
n = 0:100; x1 = rand(1,length(n));
x2 = sqrt(10)*randn(1,length(n)); u = stepseq(0,0,100);
y1 = x1.*u; y2 = x2.*u; y = (x1 + x2).*u;
diff = sum(abs(y - (y1 + y2)));
if (diff < 1e-5)
disp(’ *** System-1 is Linear *** ’);
else
disp(’ *** System-1 is NonLinear *** ’);
end
```

--I cannot find the equivalent of stepseq command to scilab. thankss

Comment: As far as I know, Scilab doesn't have such equivalent. In fact `stepseq` is not even a native MATLAB function. You will probably have to find `stepseq` wherever you found this piece of code and translate it to Scilab by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the translation (stepseq code found with a simple Google search). The only thing I changed to your code is the commenting chars (`//` instead of `%`) and the call to `randn(..)` (changed to `rand(...,"normal")`)

```
// P0211a: To prove that the system T1[x(n)] = x(n)u(n) is linear
clear; clc; close all;

function [x,n] = stepseq(n0,n1,n2)
  n=n1:n2;
  x = [(n-n0)>=0];
end

n = 0:100; x1 = rand(1,length(n));
x2 = sqrt(10)*rand(1,length(n),"normal"); u = stepseq(0,0,100);
y1 = x1.*u; y2 = x2.*u; y = (x1 + x2).*u;
diff = sum(abs(y - (y1 + y2)));
if (diff < 1e-5)
  disp(" *** System-1 is Linear *** ");
else
  disp(" *** System-1 is NonLinear *** ");
end
```

Comment: So what ? Didi you test the above ?